# How to simplify this expression in bra-ket / Dirac notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, notation

I am trying to review my basic quantum and I somehow ended up with this expression:
$$
\frac{\langle m | \partial H | m \rangle}{\langle n | \partial H | n \rangle}
\frac{\langle m | \partial H | n \rangle}{\langle n | \partial H | m \rangle},
$$
where $|m\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$ are eigenstates of $H$, and $\partial$ takes the derivative with respect to some parameter of the Hamiltonian $H$.
I know that if I can sum over all states, the projection operator $\Sigma_m |m\rangle\langle m |=1$. However, it doesn't seem to be the case.
I could also have made a mistake and have had to deal with:
$$
\frac{\langle m | \partial H | m \rangle}{\langle n | \partial H | n \rangle}
\frac{\langle n | \partial H | m \rangle}{\langle m | \partial H | n \rangle}.
$$

Does anyone have any hints on how I could simplify either of these further to the simplest expression? I could be missing some trivial relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we suppose $H + \varepsilon \,\partial H$ should still be a valid Hamiltonian and thus Hermitian, than $\partial H$ must also be Hermitian. The second fraction is thus equal to 1.